# PLS-00201: identifier 'ISDATE' must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

The following is my procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_InsertNewCustomer( IN_CustName IN VARCHAR,
                                                    IN_CustContact IN VARCHAR,
                                                    IN_DateOfBirth IN VARCHAR,
                                                    IN_CustAddress IN VARCHAR,
                                                    IN_PostalCode IN VARCHAR) AS
v_newCustID customer.customerID%TYPE;
v_newAddressID customeraddress.addressid%TYPE;
v_location number(5);
e_invalidDate exception;
e_invalidPostalCode exception;

BEGIN

   IF (ISDATE(IN_DateOfBirth) = false) THEN
       raise e_invalidDate;
   ELSE
       IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT locationid FROM location WHERE locationpostcode = IN_PostalCode) THEN
             raise e_invalidPostalCode;
       ELSE
             v_location := locationid;   
       END IF;
   END IF;

   v_newCustID := 'C'||customerID.nextval;
   v_newAddressID := addressid.nextval;

   INSERT INTO customer values(v_newCustID, IN_CustName, IN_CustContact, TO_DATE(IN_DateOfBirth,'dd/mm/yyyy'));
   INSERT INTO customeraddress values(TO_NUMBER(v_newAddressID, '999'), IN_CustAddress, v_location);
   INSERT INTO addresslist values(TO_NUMBER(v_newAddressID, '999'), v_newCustID, 1);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(chr(10));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('New staff added successfully.');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(chr(10));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Customer ID: '||v_newCustID);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Customer Name: '||IN_CustName);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Customer Contact: '||IN_CustContact);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Customer Birthday: '||IN_DateOfBirth);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Customer Address ID: '||v_newAddressID);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Customer Address: '||IN_CustAddress);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Postal Code: '||v_location);

EXCEPTION
     WHEN e_invalidDate THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Input: Wrong Date of Birth input.');
     WHEN e_invalidPostalCode THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Input: PostalCode does not exist.');
        rollback;

END;
/
```

And I got some error which is

```
14/4     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
14/8     PLS-00201: identifier 'ISDATE' must be declared
24/4     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
24/24    PLS-00201: identifier 'CUSTOMERID.NEXTVAL' must be declared
25/4     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
25/22    PLS-00201: identifier 'ADDRESSID.NEXTVAL' must be declared
```

My customer id will be :

C00001
C00002
C00003
......

My address id will be :

```
001
002
003
...
501
502
```

i would like to increase the customerid with the .nextval and also the address id but i cant figure out what to do. Seeking for help.

Comment: Oracle has no function `isdate()`.  Either define one yourself or use a different mechanism (such as converting to a date and catching the error).

Comment: You also don't seem to have created the sequences you are trying to use. Why are you passing all the arguments as strings, instead of declaring the procedure parameters as the correct data types for the data they represent? If you made `IN_DateOfBirth ` a DATE, for instance, then you wouldn't need to test it or convert it inside the procedure - the caller would have to provide a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has not function `ISDATE` for checking string type. But you can write your own function and use it. For example:

```
function my_is_date( p_str in varchar2 ) return number
is
    v_date date;
begin
    v_date := to_date(p_str, 'dd.mm.yyyy');
    return 1;
exception
    when others then
        return 0;
end;
```